# x-axis values not coming properly in .net chart

Tags: c#, charts

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    chart.Series.Add("SS" + i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < dtRpt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(dtRpt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0], dtRpt.Rows[i].ItemArray[4]);
    chart.Series[1].Points.AddXY(dtRpt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0], dtRpt.Rows[i].ItemArray[5]);
    System.Drawing.Color col = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#3F66B1");
    System.Drawing.Color col1 = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#DD3B26");
    chart.Series[0].Color = col;
    chart.Series[1].Color = col1;
}
```

Image of chart some of the chart x-axis is not visible;can anyone help me to resolve.

[image]

Comment: What are those x values? I can see `Food, Patterns and Shapes` I think they are x axis values only

Comment: actually there are 16 topics but only few are coming

Comment: Can anyone share relevant links to create multiple series chart